# Autorun firefox extension jpm

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I need help with `JPM`. I am trying to develop a firefox extension with `JPM`. I would like my extension automatically launches when opening firefox, but I can't add an event on the `onLoad` I know that with the overlay I can do something like :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){  
    console.log("hello");   
},false);
```

If I add this event to my JPM extension gives me an error :

> JPM [error]   Message: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Is it possible to do that with `JPM` ? Or is there another way to launch my firefox extension to the opening?

Comment: where did you put this script?

Comment: I put this script in my `index.js`, this file is create automatically by `jpm init`. I followed this tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29 @Fast Snail

Comment: in this tutorial i cant see `window.addEventListener` .? i think you cant use this in `index.js` but you can use it in content script

Comment: Yes I cant see `window.addEventListener` me to, but I wonder how to do this with `jpm`, how to say is my firefox extension should start at start-up browser ?

Answer (score 3):

Your extension already gets loaded when you launch firefox.

How do you think the `window.addEventListener` gets added in the first place? It has to execute javascript code to do that.

Comment: Yes after some research my `index.js` is load when launch firefox, so I I can do what I want in this file

Comment: @simon, If this answer solved your problem, please accept it.  That way the question will show up as having an accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

@simon, You can also listen for load and unload events.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload

Therefore, if you add an exports.main = function() {} in index.js, the code inside that function will be run as soon as Firefox starts up and your add-on is loaded.